# C++ template class Type being forwarded as parameter to object's template function

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-passing, forwarding

Ok, I don't know if the title made much sense, so I will just show the code:

```
template <class S,class P,class A> class Task
{
  protected:

    timeval start;
    boost::ptr_vector<S> states;
    boost::ptr_vector<P> policies;
    Agent &robot;
    const ACTION_MODE &a_mode;
    A algo;

  public:

    Task(Agent &a, ACTION_MODE &m, A &alg) : robot(a), a_mode(m), algo(alg) {};
    P* findPolicy(S *state);
    bool stateExists(S *state);
    bool if_appendState(S *state);
    bool policyExists(P *policy);
    bool if_appendPolicy(P *policy);  
    void run();
};
```

Class S, is for States (a polymorphic class ) class P is for policies (a templated polymoprhic class) and class A is for Algorithm classes.
For example (a class A - type):

```
class SarsaTD
{
  protected:
    const float gamma;
    const float alpha;
    PTYPE method;
  public:
    SarsaTD(float a, float g) : alpha (a), gamma (g) {method = ON_POLICY; };
    template <typename P> void optimize(P *policy);
    PTYPE getType();
};
```

I am trying to use from class Task's parameter P (policies) and forward it into a method of an instance of SarsaTD.

```
template <class S,class P,class A> void Task<S,P,A>::run()
{
  S *state = new S(Task<S,P,A>::robot, const_cast<ACTION_MODE&>(Task<S,P,A>::a_mode));
  P *policy;
  if (Task<S,P,A>::if_appendState(state))
  {
    policy = new P(state);
    Task<S,P,A>::if_appendPolicy(policy);
  }
  else
  {
    policy = Task<S,P,A>::findPolicy(const_cast<S *>(state));
    policy->getValue();
    delete state;
  }

  Task<S,P,A>::algo.optimize<P>(policy);
  wb_robot_step(TIME_STEP);
}
```

Everythign works fine, untill the line: `Task<S,P,A>::algo.optimize<P>(policy);`
Where the compiler gives the following error:

```
task.hpp:174: error: expected-primary expression before '>'token
```

If I understand this correctly, the Parameter type P (policy) I use throughout the template class cannot be forwarded properly into the template function ?
Or is my syntax wrong ? Or what I am trying to do simply makes no sense ?

Comment: Do you even need to do `Task<S,P,A>::algo`? `algo` is a member variable of `this` so shouldn't just `algo.optimize<P>(policy);` do the trick? That goes for the other invocations you have also. And why is `a_mode` declared const when its not really const?

Comment: I've tried them too, both:
this->algo.optimize<P>(policy);
and
algo.optimize<P>(policy);
and I still get the exact same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Task<S,P,A>::algo.optimize<P>(policy);
```

At that point it can't know whether `optimize` is a value or not. You'll understand if you just look at

```
Task<S,P,A>::algo.optimize < P
```

This not only looks like a comparison to you, but also to the compiler. Even if it then proceeds with parsing, it can't know whether your intention was a comparison or a template argument list, unless it fully instantiates the template type. If you search for "dependent name" and "two phase lookup", you'll find some useful information. The solution in your case would be manual disambiguation. Tell the compiler that `optimize` is a template:

```
Task<S,P,A>::algo.template optimize<P>(policy);
```

Comment: OMG, thank you that worked. I had no idea such problems could arise by passing template types as parameters.
Thank you again, I will look into dependent name !

Comment: If you'd like a complete reference, I would recommend Vandevoorde/Josuttis "C++ Templates: A complete guide". I also hear only good of Dave Abrahams template book, but I would think Vandevoorde is more concise.

Comment: Oh there's also some valuable information on http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html .

Answer (score 2):

You use a template parameter in another part of the expression, try to do :

```
Task<S, P, A>::algo.template optimize<P>(policy)
```

This should work like that.

Comment: I've tried that, and i get:
       task.hpp:175: error: expected unqualified-id before 'typename'
       task.hpp:175: error: expected ';' before 'typename'

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Task<S, P, A>::template algo.optimize<P>(policy)`?

Comment: I've tried that too, and it gives exactly the same error: expected-primary expression before '>'token

Comment: the `template` must precede that member instead ;)

Comment: yes, that's it! Just been confused, sorry. I correct my answer

Comment: Ah, I just read your answer, thought "it should be template, not typename", and didn't really look at the position. :)

Comment: Yes, I was half sleeping when I wrote the answer :)